# Auto Vertical Height in ListView.builder

Tags: flutter

How can i do vertical listview with different height of items. I have `listview.builder` in `listview.builder`. My inner listview have different count of items. So i need Auto Vertical Height in ListView. Could you help me?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gKnE.png)

Comment: Please add some sample code of what you have so far

Comment: slivers are your best bet, they are a whole topic in flutter https://medium.com/flutter/slivers-demystified-6ff68ab0296f